# I cannot enter data in KOrganizer

Tags: korganizer

I just installed KOrganizer 4.8.5.  I read the manual and then tried to enter 1) event 2)ToDo.  It seemed to accept the data, but nothing appeared in calendar or ToDo list.It all seems very simple, but I am not getting anywhere. I am new to Ubuntu.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

you could determine where korganizer is in your system with:

```
whereis korganizer
```

then due to output you could check file-permissions with:

`ls -al /name-of-path/bin-or-else/korganizer`

### what output does korganizer have after ls -al ?!

This is what I got:

```
jeads@james-X201EP:~$ ls -al /usr/bin/korganizer
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 61608 Sep  8  2012 /usr/bin/korganizer
```

Comment: there is missing a 'w' here -rwxr-xr(w)x - then you would be permitted to write something with your korganizer, but you should make a link only for concerning user - not change permissions for admin - if concerning user is yourself (without internet) - then it would be no problem simply to change permissions with : sudo chmod 757 /usr/bin/korganizer - but I would prefer to make a link

Comment: The permissions of the executable should not affect the ability to save data.