# Korganizer adding events

Tags: kde, korganizer

I am new to Linux and to Korganizer 4.13.3. To learn the latter, I am following the tutorial from their web site:

https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/kdepim/korganizer/five-minute-course.html#course-entering-events

When I click in the agenda view, and enter information about an event, it doesn't save any information, but I get the following message:

> You created an incidence in a calender that is currently filtered out.
>   On the left sidebar, enable it in the calender manager to see the
>   incidence.

I am not seeing a calendar manager in my left sidebar, and have no idea how to proceed (I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, and I get this same problem whether I am in Unity or KDE (I am using Kubuntu)).

**Related question**

[I cannot enter data in KOrganizer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/519258/i-cannot-enter-data-in-korganizer)

Answer (score 2):

With the a window labeled *Calendar - Korganizer* open click *View* and then *Filter*, the last line on the drop-down menu.  I have it working with *(x) Nofilter* selected.

Just in case it's relevant to the 'cure', before I discovered this, I also thought there being no filters present was the problem, and so, added a dummy with no rules.  In the drop-down Menu, I selected my dummy entry first, and the entries popped into view on the Calendar.  Then I experimented by selecting *Nofilter*, thinking the entries might disappear, *but they remained*.  Probably the dummy filter was unnecessary, but I have no idea.

As far as I can see, in fact, there is *no* 'Calendar Manager' in the left-hand panel, unless that refers to a check-box to the left of the calendar icon??  The tool-tip's wording seems somewhat misleading, in the absence of further information being supplied -- from somewhere.

For more information, refer to [Chapter 4. Views and Filters](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/kdepim/korganizer/chapter-views-and-filters.html).

Comment: Seems to be working in Ubuntu 16 for me, on the computer I just built from scratch. Will check later today in the computer in which I was having this issue!

Answer (score 0):

To the left of your calender is an area that says "search". Try checking "personal calendar", and then you should be able to add "incidents".